# Call Python function with *args and **kwargs from C API

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm writing some C level function, it should accept a callable, `*args` and `**kwargs`, print something and call the callable with arguments. It's signature should be reflecting this one from Python:

```py
def my_function(callable, *args, **kwargs): ...
```

Here's the C code that I have:

```c
static PyObject *call_c(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords) {
    PyObject *f;
    PyObject *arguments;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|O", &f, &arguments))
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "invalid args");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Calling...\n");

    return PyObject_Call(f, arguments, keywords);
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to execute it:

```py
def printer(value="test"):
    print(f"printed: {value}")

def call_c_wrapper(callable, *args, **kwargs):
    call_c(callable, args, **kwargs)

call_c(print, "some print value")
# Calling...
# Segmentation fault

call_c(printer, value="test")
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
#     call_c(printer, value="test")
# TypeError: call_c() takes no keyword arguments

call_c_wrapper(print, "some print value")
# > this is the only one that works:

# Calling...
# some print value

call_c_wrapper(printer, value="my value")
# > same as `call_c` with kwargs:

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
#     call_c_wrapper(printer, value="my value")
#   File "main.py", line 32, in call_c_wrapper
#     call_c(callable, args, **kwargs)
#  TypeError: call_c() takes no keyword arguments
```

What I'm doing wrong with the code? The `*args` parsing seems somewhat working, I'm OK with using a wrapper function if that's necessary, but why `**kwargs` doesn't work at all?

### Edit

I've changed the `PyMethodDef` from `METH_VARARGS` to `METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS`, so `call_c_wrapper()` now works fine.
The `call_c` with `args` still gives me `SegmentationFault`, and the one with `kwargs` raises `MemoryError`.

Comment: I see a bunch of bugs, but the one that caused the "call_c() takes no keyword arguments" error is probably in code you didn't show us. Show us the PyMethodDef for `call_c`.

Comment: You probably screwed up the flags in the PyMethodDef. Besides that, your `args` handling works more like `def call_c(f, args **kwargs)` than `def call_c(f, *args, **kwargs)`, which is why you got that segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - you're right - I forgot about `PyMethodDef`, after fixing it, the `call_c_wrapper()` works fine, but calling directly `call_c()` raises errors. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in [the comments to your now-deleted earlier version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858355/call-python-function-with-args-and-kwargs-from-c-api): I think `PyArg_ParseTuple` is the wrong tool for this because it doesn't really have a mechanism for handling `*args`.

What you want to do is something like the following Python code:

```
def f(*args, **kwds):
    f = args[0]
    args = args[1:]

    return f(*args, **kwds)
```

The easiest way of doing this is just to use the `PyTuple_...` API (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html).

Something along the lines of:

```c
static PyObject *call_c(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords) {
    PyObject *f;
    PyObject *arguments;

    if (PyTuple_Size(args) == 0)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Missing argument 'f'");
        return NULL;
    }
    f = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0); // Note: borrowed reference so no reference counting needed
    arguments = PyTuple_GetSlice(args, 1, PyTuple_Size(args));
    // ideally you should check arguments isn't NULL too

    printf("Calling...\n");

    PyObject* result = PyObject_Call(f, arguments, keywords);
    Py_XDECREF(arguments);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a problem using the `PyTuple_GetSlice` - now I get it